# VueJS, Laravel 5.5, перенос маршрута из web.php в api.php

Tags: vue.js, laravel5

В web.php есть такой маршрут:

```
Route::get('/movies', 'MovieController@getMovies');
```

Функция **getMovies()** в контроллере возвращает некоторый набор данных, а не представление. Поэтому хочу перенести маршрут из **web.php** в **api.php**, где ему и место. Но после переноса и компиляции вызов функции getMovies() больше не происходит.

Сам вызов с параметром **/movies** производится из метода объекта Vue, вот этот метод:

```
readMovies()
    {
        axios.get('/api/movies')
        .then(response => {
            this.movies = response.data.user_movies;
        });
    },
```

где **this.movies** переменная объекта Vue, которая должна принять результат, а **user_movies** набор с результатами возвращаемый функцией **getMovies()** в контроллере **MovieController**.

Пробовал менять запрос в методе на следующие:

```
axios.get('api/movies')
axios.get('./api/movies')
axios.get('/movies')
axios.get('movies')
```

Браузер показывает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно изменить чтобы маршрут заработал?

Answer (score 1):

Вам сервер 401 отдает, следовательно для начала вам необходимо авторизоваться.

Ваш КЭП :)

Comment: Но я авторизован, в правом верхнем углу вижу имя пользователя.
Попробовал выйти и авторизовался по новой, всё также.

Comment: м, а вы уверены что не путаете вход в админку к примеру, с доступом к api ? Для доступа к api обычно нужен ключ доступа(token)

Comment: API это внешний интерфейс так сказать, т.е. доступ к сайту из вне. Так вот, чтобы получить доступ, вы даете ключ доступа(персональный или общий для всех, себе или еще кому-то), тем самым давая возможность (мобильному приложению например) делать запросы к вашему api, а чтобы ограничить доступ и нужен токен - вы ведь не хотите чтобы у вас стягивали данные все подряд ?

Comment: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/passport#использование Похоже это то что вам нужно.

Comment: В самом конце инструкции не понял, где проверить настройки Vue на предмет присутствия вот этих настроек:

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

  next();
});

Comment: Ну вот, отлично. А теперь аккуратно добавьте в самом верху то что указано в доках. _рановато, видать, я за это дело взялся_ - опыт сам по себе не появляется. А что-то делать вы никогда не будете готовы на все 100%, веб очень быстр в плане развития, пока будете учить одно, появится другое,это как гонка воорожений(ну или типа того) :) Поэтому хорошие доки и ровные руки наше все, а руки то как раз и становятся все ровнее и ровнее вместе с опытом :)

Comment: _ругается на undefined property http_ Самый простой вариант - добавить `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас просто некогда, пока притормозил с этим, продолжу позже.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70065/discussion-on-answer-by---vuejs-laravel-5-5----web).